# Activate PHP8.1 on InstantWP running Alpine 3.16

Tags: wordpress, alpine-linux, php-8

**Context**

I am using **Instant WordPress**, and the latest downloadable version is v5.3.6 as per link below:
https://github.com/webtoolsgroup/InstantWP/releases

This includes an Alpine v3.6.5 distro and PHP v7.1.10 in its QEMU image by default. Here is the architecture if interested:
[image]

Wordpress 6.x has been released, which supports php8.x, so I want to update the whole thing.

**Already done**

Until now, I have done the following updates successfully:

- WordPress --> v6.1.1
- Alpine -->  v3.16.4
- All packages updated to latest
- APK add / upgrade php81

**Problem**

```
> localhost:~$ sudo apk add php81 --allow-untrusted
(1/2) Installing php81-common (8.1.17-r0)
(2/2) Installing php81 (8.1.17-r0)
Executing busybox-1.35.0-r17.trigger
OK: 346 MiB in 188 packages
> localhost:~$ php -v
PHP 7.1.10 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2017 12:31:49) ( NTS )
```

I still have PHP 7.1 running.
If upgrading is not enough, how can I switch to PHP 8.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the `PHP - v` version by updating manually the `php` link in `/usr/bin` to point at php81 instead of php71.

Also instantWP had no update for years...
Best option is to switch to "local by Flywheel"